# android do not know why requestLocationUpdate not working on my phone

Tags: android, google-maps, location

Follow simple code in google location. I use:

```
gmap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    gmap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                3000, 0, this);
```

[image: Sign app to use get SHA1 to register API key to run in mobile]

In method location change, i used Toast to show message. In genymotion, It running OK but in my Phone, requestLocationUpdates seem not running. hmmm,GPS ,3G enbled. and Map displayed, I think problem is not by API_KEY, so what problem is ?? :((, i restart my phone , but no thing changed

Comment: Since you're using GPS, most likely you aren't able to see the satellites.  DO you have a GPS icon flashing in your notification bar?  If so, that is the problem.  Note that you will almost never be able to get a GPS signal inside a building, go outside to test, or use a mock location provider.

Comment: oh god.... thank you, now is 2:30 AM, I think I have to wait for along time to test :(